# Error in if method with multiple conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get user input to fill a variable with a number that is <=1 and <=24. Currently it goes only to the else statement and prints those two lines and awaits another input. Even if the input satisfies the three conditions.

Eg. I am entering 1. This should satisfy all three conditions?

The program should provide the user with an error corresponding to their issue with the input.

Where if an integer is not entered it asks to enter only numbers. If the number is <1 or >24 it should ask to only enter numbers between those two points.

```
    while (length1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        System.out.print("Enter the Length of wall 1: ");
        if (scan.hasNextInt() && 1<=length1 && length1<=24) {
            length1 = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else if (length1<1 && 24<length1) {
            System.out.println("Error Error");
            System.out.println("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 24.");
            scan.next();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Error");
            System.out.println("Please only enter numbers.");
            scan.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `length1<1 && 24<length1` So, length is smaller 1 AND bigger 24? Did you mean _or_, i.e. `||`?

Comment: @tobias_k Ah, I should change it to || then. Yes It should be or. That still gives me the else statement error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides one wrong `&&`, reading nextInt should be done first.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter the Length of wall 1: ");
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        length1 = scan.nextInt();
        if (1 <= length1 && length1 <= 24) {
            break:
        }
        System.out.println("Error Error");
        System.out.println("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 24.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error Error");
        System.out.println("Please only enter numbers.");
        scan.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I added another scan.next(); after the exception for "numbers between 1 and 24" as it would skip to the next method if I entered a string and then the second time a wrong number.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Code:

```
while (length1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    System.out.print("Enter the Length of wall 1: ");
    if (scan.hasNextInt() && 1<=length1 && length1<=24) {
        length1 = scan.nextInt();
    }
    else if (length1<1 || 24<length1) {
        System.out.println("Error Error");
        System.out.println("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 24.");
        scan.next();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error Error");
        System.out.println("Please only enter numbers.");
        scan.next();
    }
}
```